# How to represent clusters in MATLAB?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, k-means

Suppose I have the following data sets:

**A**:

```
1   8   9   12
2   1   0   35
7   0   0   23
```

**B**:

```
6 3 
1 9
0 7
```

What I want to do is for each row in B, find the smallest value and get the column index from which it appears in. For example, for row 1 from **B**, the smallest value is **3** which comes from column **2**. Therefore add row 1 from **A** to `Cluster 2`.

For row 2 from `B`, the smallest value is **1**, which comes from column `1`. Therefore add row 2 from **A** to `Cluster 1`. And so on...

Now I want to make an array called **C** (this will represent my clusters) with 2 items. Item 1 contains the matrix of all rows from A that should be in `Cluster 1`, and Item 2 contains the matrix of all rows from A that should be in `Cluster 2`. This is where I'm having problems. This is my current attempt:

```
function clusterSet = buildClusters(A, B)
clusterSet = zeros(size(B, 2)); % Number of clusters = number of columns in B
for i = 1:size(A, 1)
    [value, index] = min(B(i,:)); % Get the minimum value of B in row i, and its index (column number)
    clusterSet(index) = A(i,:); % Add row i from A to its corresponding cluster's matrix. 
end
end
```

I'm getting the following error on the last line (note: this is not explicitly referring to my data sets 'A' and 'B', but talks about a general A and B):

```
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must
be the same.
```

If the minimum value of **B** in row 1 comes from column 2, then row 1 from A should be added to a matrix `Cluster 2` (row of B corresponds to which row of A to add to the cluster, and the column of B represents which cluster to add it to). This is what I want that line to do but I get the above error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Make `C` a cell array. Then it can have elements of unequal sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way without loops:

```
[~, cluster] = min(B,[],2); %// get cluster index of each row
[clusterSort, indSort] = sort(cluster); %// sort cluster indices
sz = accumarray(clusterSort,1); %// size of each cluster
C = mat2cell(A(indSort,:), sz); %// split A into cell array based on clusters
```